# How to access ng-model in ng-repeat without using dot(.)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How could i access ng-model value in controller without dot(.) c.newComment i just want to use ng-model="newComment".

```
<div ng-repeat="c in q.comments">
<input  type="text" ng-model="c.newComment" size="30" >                 
<button   ng-click="reply()">Reply</button>
</div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should not do this because of scope inheritance, watch [this](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot) video for more info.

Answer (score 0):

**If you find like this, then may be it will be helpful to you.**

```
 <tr ng-repeat="item in configList">

                                            <td align="center" >
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Configuration[item.Name]" value="{{item.Value}}" ng-model="Configuration[item.Name]" ng-bind="Configuration[item.Name]" onkeypress="return checkNumberPhone(event,this);" required />

                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
```

**You can get this value in controller like following:**

```
var configlist = $scope.configList;

var configArray = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < configlist.length; i++) {

            var objConfig = new Object();
            objConfig.Name = configlist[i].Name;
            objConfig.Value = $scope.Configuration[configlist[i].Name] != undefined ? $scope.Configuration[configlist[i].Name] : configlist[i].Value;
            objConfig.CompanyId = localStorage.getItem("CompanyId");
            configArray.push(objConfig);
        }
```

**Actully this will work on index/name base**